# github: can no longer commit changes

Tags: git, netbeans, github

I had everything working for over a month and all of a sudden I can no longer commit my changes.

I use netbeans ide and when I commit changes, in the popup I see the message:'No files available for commit.'

When I try to do a push to remote, I select my git repository location (same as usual) but when I click on Next to select local branch, there's nothing showing.

Has anyone encounter this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You may have switched branches, but not created a new 'local branch' for this remote branch.. Netbeans now does not know where to commit to. Also, as there is no local branche, you can not push local to remote.
I had this problem with Netbeans before, after a few branche switches.

Try to switch to the correct branche (even if you only have one branche).

Comment: Thanks but I could not switch to other branches since I don't see any in netbeans... In the end, I deleted everything and re-cloned the whole repository. That fixed it, let's hope in won't happen again.